# Free Energy in Cahn-Hilliard Equation

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry

i have got a question regarding the derivation of the Cahn-Hilliard equation.
I am espacially referring to the following paper: https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1695731

In this paper he defines the Free Helmholtz Energy of a inhomogeneous composition as follows:

$F= \int_V f(c_0)+\kappa(\nabla c)^2dV$

So, i am no expert in Free Energies.. maybe someone can help me out.
Cahn uses the Helmholtz Energy, is it possible to instead use the Gibbs Energy?
As long as I know, it is usual to use the Helmholtz Energy when the volume is preserved and the Gibbs Energy when the pressure is preserved... So i thought, that maybe the phase seperation causes a pressure difference.

If this is the reason, why isn`t it possible to use the Gibbs Energy when the pressure is not preserved?

Thanks a lot! (I hope I expressed myself clearly :))